How much sample mass could Apollo 11 have brought back?
Apollo 11 brought back about 20 kg of lunar samples.  How much could the astronauts have brought back?  Could they have packed the sample-return containers full (60 kg each, by my calculations)?  Strapped a boulder to the ascent engine cover?  Packed the ascent module with souvenirs until it resembled a clown car?

I presume you want all astronauts returning as well?

They would've had to transfer any samples from the ascent module to the command module, so they couldn't go too crazy.

According to this answer the primary limitation on sample return was how much mass could be chucked out of the LM before takeoff, so probably they were pretty close to the practical limit.

Apollo 17 brought back 110.5 kg (ref)

Apollo 11 - 44 lbs, (20kg),
Apollo 12 - 75 lbs, (34kg),
Apollo 14 - 98 lbs, (45kg),
Apollo 15 - 173 lbs, (79kg),
Apollo 16 - 210 lbs, (95kg),
Apollo 17 - 253 lbs, (115kg). Source - I don't remember it's just in my notes.

The limitation was weight, not volume. They used a small sample scale on the surface to weigh each sample so that they could stay within limits. Certainly there were margins, which could explain part of the increase for each mission as the margins were reduced, but probably there were a lot of factors that affected the weight calculation including ascent trajectory. I suppose the actual answer would be if they removed all margin, that would be the maximum they could carry.

They could theoretically try to bring back as much as they want. No guarantee they'd survive it though.

The volume of rock wasn't really an issue in the Lunar Module; the lift mass was the limiting factor, so strapping luggage to the roof rack wouldn't be necessary. But also, it wouldn't have worked. Once the lunar module had left the surface of the Moon (leaving behind its lower half and most of the astronauts' equipment), the astronauts weren't going back outside. Anything they wanted to bring home had to fit inside the stowage cabinets in the LM and then be manually transferred into the Apollo capsule for reentry.
That said, Apollo 11 was extremely conservative with their margins. They weren't interested in bringing back as much material as possible (the goal was to just get home safely), so they didn't get close to the limits of their maximum launch weight. Once the system had been proven out, the later missions reduced the safety margins as they felt more comfortable with the LM's reliability.
Apollo 11 returned with 21.6 kilograms of rock and dust aboard, 12 came back with over 34 kilograms, and 14 carried off 42 kilograms of moon samples.
Apollo 13 didn't bring any back, for obvious reasons, and Apollo 15 - 17 were the "J-class" missions, using a redesigned LM, so while they brought back much larger sample masses, those missions aren't necessarily comparable to Apollo 11.
So that gives us a basis to start from. Apollo 11 and Apollo 14 were using the same LM design, so theoretically Apollo 11 could have at least doubled their return load and still made it back. Even 14 could have added more stuff and likely still made it back, but at that point they really had cut the margins as short as anyone was comfortable with. There's a point where it's hard to estimate what the limits are because nobody was willing to get too close to them and risk watching a crew crash into the lunar surface.
To my knowledge, each mission was given a maximum sample mass based on what the engineering team was comfortable with, and they just did their best to hit that number. I'm not convinced the LM had any specifically stated cargo limit external to the mission profile. Presumably they had ample stowage for all the rock they could possibly carry.

Were there any published limits?

I've read through the surface journal for Apollo 12, and I don't recall seeing any conversations about weight limits, just ones about "how much do you have?" and "where is it stored?".  The limitations on sampling seemed to be more along the lines of "how many small, interesting rocks can I spot?"

And, did the crew have any way to weigh the samples to make sure they didn't exceed the limits? Or was it just "fill up the containers and you'll be good"?

@OrganicMarble - there was a sample scale that they used at least on later missions. However whether it was used for each and every sample bag I don't know. Per Mark's comment if the astronauts are not heard calling out sample weights all the time then maybe not very often. Maybe they did just fill up containers, which is obviously a known volume, and based on an estimated average density might be close enough, probably keeping rocks and regolith samples separate.

@OrganicMarble I don't think there were any limits imposed by the LM itself. The mission plan certainly must have had a maximum sample mass (presumably very close to what they actually recovered) since launch weight was such a priority that they left most of their tools and stuff on the moon, but if there's a public document that has it listed, I haven't been able to find it.  Lots of "here's what they did" and very little "here's what the plan said".

Did the J mission LMs have increased ascent-stage tankage? I thought all the upgrading was done to the descent stage.

According to Apollo By The Numbers Apollo 14 had 150 kg of fuel remaining in the ascent stage at jettison, less than either A11 or A12, so if you were willing to give up all your safety margin, you could give up that much fuel for cargo. A15 had the least fuel remaining at ascent stage jettison, 132 kg.

@RussellBorogove I'm looking at your link (which I have no reason to doubt) and what appears to be a 2020 document from NASA, and they disagree on the ascent stage dry masses and propellant loads for Apollo 11, 12, and 14 (probably elsewhere too but that's what I'm looking at). Especially 11, where "my" document says the LM weighed almost 250 kg more and had an equivalently smaller fuel load but "yours" lists the dry and fuel masses as nearly the same across all three. I'm baffled.

@DarthPseudonym "Mine" (really Tyson's, after Orloff's) cites contemporary Apollo post-mission documents, but I've caught errors in it before. I don't care enough to go check Orloff's version or the primary sources.
